# wuauserv keeps stopping over and over

Tags: windows-update

As opposed to the forum post [How do you prevent wuauserv (Windows Update Service) from restarting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/300463/how-do-you-prevent-wuauserv-windows-update-service-from-restarting) the problem I'm facing is that I don't want Windows update to stop. My monitoring system keeps spamming me with notifications that the service has stopped.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Is it known why the service keeps quitting? Event viewer doesn't tell me anything.

-- Jaapyse

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If a particular answer was helpful, you should press the green check image next to the question to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the previous answer, if the service is set to Auto (Trigger Start), it appears that the service will be stopped and started by the system as needed, and won't be running all the time.

If you need the service running all the time, you may need to remove the trigger:
http://michlstechblog.info/blog/windows-remove-trigger-to-start-or-stop-a-service/

Answer (score 0):

You probably have already checked this, but are you sure that the Windows Update service state has been set to automatic? (And not triggered or something else?)

If the service state checks out okay, then you'll need to troubleshoot why the service is stopping in the first place. Have a look at c:\windows\WindowsUpdate.log. When the wuauserv service stops normally, there should be a line with "END" and an associated exit code. You can look up the exit code to see why the service is stopping. If the service has stopped and there is no line with "END" then the service is probably stopping abnormally. In any case, WindowsUpdate.log should give you some clues as to what is happening.